# Solana web3 Program constructor is expecting a json as one of params

Tags: reactjs, typescript, solana, anchor-solana

I am working with typescript react and I need help with how to fix the issue. My constructor object is expecting one of the arguments to be Idl type which is basically a json generated from solana. How do i fix this?

[image: Error i am getting]
[image: Object properties]
[image: object i am importing]

Comment: Please provide more information. Not sure what you're using, or what the actual error is

Comment: @JacobCreech i have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

yeah there is a weird thing with TypeScript and the IdlType on args if you look into the IDL object representation.

It is related to this line:

```
export declare type IdlType = "bool" | "u8" | "i8" | "u16" | "i16" | "u32" | "i32" | "f32" | "u64" | "i64" | "f64" | "u128" | "i128" | "bytes" | "string" | "publicKey" | IdlTypeDefined | IdlTypeOption | IdlTypeCOption | IdlTypeVec | IdlTypeArray;
```

The way fixed it is by using a workaround:

```
import YOUR_IDL_JSON_OBJECT from '../config/abiSolana/solanaIDL.json'

      const a = JSON.stringify(YOUR_IDL_JSON_OBJECT)
      const b = JSON.parse(a)
      return new Program(b, address, provider)
```

When you do this the compiler should not scream at you. If someone cares to explain what the hell is wrong with the enum there, I would be happy. :)

Comment: The reason this works is because `JSON.parse(a)` is typed `any`, so the compiler has no idea what you're passing as `b` any more.

You'd probably be better doing `YOUR_IDL_JSON_OBJECT as Idl` instead

Comment: If you use `as` operator then you can't use custom methods. There must be a better way.